# Add checkbox values to a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to add checked checkbox values as url parameter to my link.
This is what I have amongst others:

```
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx1=1"> <label for="box1"></label>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx2=1"> <label for="box1"></label>

<script>
    $(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
        var values = [];
        $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            var result = $(this).val();
            values.push(result);
        });
        var key = $(".link").html(values.join("&"));
        document.write('<a href="http://www.example.com/test.html?' + key + '">Open here</a>');
    });
</script>
```

The expected result is "http://www.example.com/test.html?bx1=1&bx2=1".
I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks for these lines:

```
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx1=1"> <label for="box1"></label>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx2=1"> <label for="box1"></label>
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com/test.html">Open here</a>

<script>
    $(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
        console.log('fzef');
        var values = [];
        $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            var result = $(this).val();
            values.push(result);
        });
        $(".link").attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join("&"));
    });

    // Init link on page load
    $(".checkbox").trigger("change");
</script>
```

I get a `&on&` between my values and it does not work on IE. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Document.write()?? However, what's your expected result? And what is the error you have?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the url in here...

Comment: That's because you setup `values` as an array so the "pasted" values are basically an Object and you need to extract the values from that object...

Comment: What is .link? Your 'key' var is defined on wrong way....

Comment: `document.write()` will close the existing document and begin writing a new one on the first checkbox click and then you'll never be able to click another one or uncheck the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx1=1"> <label for="box1"></label>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx2=1"> <label for="box1"></label>
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com/test.html">Open here</a>

<script>
    $(".checkbox").on("change", function() {console.log('fzef');
        var values = [];
        $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            var result = $(this).val();
            values.push(result);
        });
        $(".link").attr('href', 'http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join("&"));
    });

    // Init link on page load
    $(".checkbox").trigger("change");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this and all other suggestions! This works great!

Comment: When I hit the **BACK** button in my browser, the checked checkboxes are still checked, but the link does not contain the values. Any chance/idea to update the link for this case?

Comment: See my edit, you just need to force the change event on page load.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I have another problem. Using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/724/) with my checkboxes pushes the value of the checkbox currently clicked and the value of the previously clicked checkbox. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @sylvain1264 do you think you can help me with it?

Comment: Hey @vloryan, I don't understand your problem, where do you "push" the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the checkboxes in a form, give them names and let jQuery do the work with [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on("change", function() {
    var href = "http://www.example.com/test.html",
        params = $(this).serialize();

    if (params.length > 0) {
      href += "?" + params;
    }

    console.log(href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="box1" name="bx1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />bx1
  <input id="box2" name="bx2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />bx2
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correction you need to do is in the line
`var key = $(".link").html(values.join("&"));`

You need to change it to
`var key = values.join("&");`

**Why?**
Because there is no `.link` selector in your code.

Answer (score -1):

try like this:
you need with `document.write()`

```
 document.write('<a href="http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join('&') + '">http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join('&')+'</a>');
```

**OR**

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
        var values = [];
        $('.checkbox:checked').each(function() {
           var  result = $(this).val();
            values.push(result);
        });
   
    
  
  $('#url').attr('href','http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join('&') );
   $('#url').html('http://www.example.com/test.html?' + values.join('&'))
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx1=1"> <label for="box1">first</label>
<input id="box2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="bx2=1"> <label for="box1">second</label>
<button >Go</button>
<a id="url"></a>
```

Comment: `document.write()` will close the existing document and begin writing a new one on the first checkbox click and then you'll never be able to click another one or uncheck the first one.

Comment: but OP not mention with use with same page.He also write with `document.write()`

Comment: The OP's use of `document.write()` was wrong. It was just his attempt at building the string, but you can't use it with callbacks unless you intentionally want to write a new document, which is clearly not the intention here.

Comment: i am also use just print the result. I was updated with my answer.