# Check and uncheck all checkboxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using this script to check and uncheck all checkboxes:

```
$('#checkall').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    $('.chkall').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', !checked);
    $(this).data('checked', !checked);
});
```

It works great, but as soon as I uncheck several checked checkboxes after "check all" and then hit "uncheck all" and "check all" again, those previously unchecked checkboxes are not checked again. Help would be great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: why do you set `data` on the `checkall` element? why isn't it a checkbox by itself

Comment: Is checkall is a CheckBox or some other control?

Comment: your html please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might be the correct way..

Use prop instead of `attr` and group the checkbox list inside a div, just for organizing purposes. Also use the `checked` as it is, don't negate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkall').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
<label for="checkall">check / uncheck all</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />

</div>
```

Comment: Huh. Got a little problem though. When I uncheck all, all checkbox values are still transfered to [my link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693232/add-checkbox-values-to-a-link-using-javascript/40693356#40693356) as if they were checked?

Answer (score 9):

```js
$('#checkall').click(function(){
    var d = $(this).data(); // access the data object of the button
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', !d.checked); // set all checkboxes 'checked' property using '.prop()'
    d.checked = !d.checked; // set the new 'checked' opposite value to the button's data object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='checkall' data-checked='false'>check/uncheck all</button>
<input type=checkbox>
<input type=checkbox>
<input type=checkbox>
<input type=checkbox>
<input type=checkbox>
```

---

I guessed what your HTML looks like, in terms of the triggering button, but what I don't know is how you initially set the `data` on it. hope this is the way you have it coded. if not, please tell.

Comment: @Satpal - yes, data.checked. what's the problem? i don't have 27k points for not knowing what i'm doing.

Comment: Now you have edited, So now you know what was wrong. Poor answer for guy boasting  27k points

Comment: @Satpal - I was writing an answer and forgot to make a change while I was typing. kill me. please explain why do you think this is a poor answer. it works flawlessly

Comment: Code dump is not useful for novice user. I downvoted for a reason, edit and explain what you changed. My vote will change

Comment: I forgot to add `.checked` to the assignment at the bottom. and I added the assumption about how the HTML of the OP looks like, since he did not say

Comment: @Satpal - added explanation as comments for every line of js code

Comment: Worked for me...Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to get all checkboxes and check them all.

```js
$('#checkall').click(function() {

  var _this = this;
  $('#checkboxes').find('input[name="checkAll"]').each(function() {
   
    if ($(_this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
<label for="checkall">check / uncheck all</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="checkboxes" class=".chkall">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" />

</div>
```