# Clicking All checkbox of a Page without using any loop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I was asked this question in an Interview as to how to Click All checkbox/Radiobutton of a WebPage without using any loop . Clicking All the checkboxes Simultaneously ,not traversing through a WebElement List to do it one by one.Is it even possible to do that or not. Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I'd tell the interviewer that I don't think I'd be a good fit, thank them for their time, and end the interview.  As someone who has done interviews, I would never waste someone's time with a question like that.

Comment: Probably the intention of the interviewer was not to find out the One and Only right answer, but to see how comfortable you are with Selenium concepts, what sort of creative ideas you can bring to the table and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**: You can inject JavaScript into the page. JavaScript can loop (which still satisfies condition that you don't loop over WebElements) to manipulate each checkbox properties, or you can use JQuery function similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015532/check-and-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-jquery) - no explicit loop (although internally JQuery probably still loops)

**Option 2**: focus on first checkbox and then send keys(`tab` and `space`) as an ActionChain or key sequence. This may work only on some Selenium bindings and some browsers, and not on all pages as well, but as abstract solution for abstract question, it will do.

**Option 3**: As in any programming task, anything that can be done with loop, can be done with recursion. So instead of creating loop, create recursion that collects all checkboxes into long ActionChain. When recursion exits, action chain is executed, checking all checkboxes.

**Option 4**: Some languages allow to use lambda functions, e.g. use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in Java instead of loops. Something like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']") ).stream().filter(checkbox -> !checkbox.isSelected()).forEach(checkbox -> checkbox.click());
```

Although again, somewhere underneath the hood it's probably a loop, *you* are not creating any loops.

I'm sure many more options are possible. But as I said earlier, the intention of the interviewer was probably not to find out the right or practical answer, but to see how comfortable you are with Selenium concepts, and what sort of creative ideas you can bring to the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question better suited for [PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate over WebElement list to achieve this, logically there is no alternative way...If there is anyone, It must be somehow using any loop.

Comment: you can achieve this with functional programming by using a `map` function instead of iteration.